# Determine the paper size of a PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf

Is there any way to the determine the paper size of a PDF document in C#. I found a dll called [PdfPrintNet](http://www.pdfprinting.net/?gclid=CLSnsY_l_rUCFUTItAodRX4A3Q) that will allow me to specify the paper size, but it doesn't have any methods for determining the current paper size.

Comment: http://www.pdfprinting.net/help/html/62c761a8-2d3f-6760-e1fb-eccf01075981.htm is read/write, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) should be able to help you out here.

```
public float GetPageHeight(string PathToPDF)
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(PathToPDF);

    // A post script point is 0.352777778mm
    const float postScriptPoints = (float)0.352777778;

    // The height is returned in post script points from iTextSharp
    float height = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height * postScriptPoints;

    reader.Close();

    return height;

}

public float GetPageWidth(string PathToPDF)
{        
    var reader = new PdfReader(PathToPDF);

    // A post script point is 0.352777778mm
    const float postScriptPoints = (float)0.352777778;

    // The height is returned in post script points from iTextSharp
    float width = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width * postScriptPoints;   

    reader.Close();

    return width;

}
```

Code modified from [How to check a PDFs page size with iTextSharp](http://rory.streetfamily.info/PermaLink,guid,ddfebc2e-9b52-48e4-945d-9401c90d4c55.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(m);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
//size information
int wid=page.PageSize.Width
int heigh=page.PageSize.Height
```

Go through this.
Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the [PdfPrintNet](http://www.pdfprinting.net/?gclid=CLSnsY_l_rUCFUTItAodRX4A3Q) dll, you can use [`PdfPrint.PaperSize`](http://www.pdfprinting.net/help/) Property to get the parer-size of a pdf document.

Hope it helps :)